# Search for color string in powershell

Tags: string, powershell, search, colors

I have a PowerShell code. How can I search for characters within a `RichTextBox` that have a certain color formatting? Or any color at all?

Let's say red background for example. I have highlighted certain portion of text and would like to find those characters.

Currently, I have a search for text only. My code example:

```
Function example-search {

    $index = $resultbox.Find($SearchText, $resultbox.SelectionStart + $resultbox.SelectedText.length, [System.Windows.forms.RichtextBoxFinds]::None)

    if($index -ge 0)
    {
        $resultbox.select($index, $searchText.length)
        $resultbox.ScrollToCaret()
    }
    else
    {
        $index = $resultbox.Find($SearchText, 0, $resultbox.SelectionStart , 
        [System.Windows.forms.RichtextBoxFinds]::None)
    }

    if($index -ge 0)
    {
        $resultbox.select($index, $searchText.length)
        $resultbox.ScrollToCaret()
    }
    else
    {
        $resultbox.SelectionStart = 0
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it, which goes through each character in the richbox and checks for the color name. You can rearrange it to your needs

```
function SearchByColor
{
    param ([string]$color)

    $result = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $resultbox.TextLength; $i++)
    {
        $resultbox.Select($i, 1)

        if ($resultbox.SelectionColor.Name -eq $color)
        {
            $resultbox.SelectedText
        }
    }

    $result  -join ''
}
```

To use it:

```
SearchByColor Red
```

Comment: Hello Micky  thank you for the example, however this doesnt work for me. The search runs through the text and does not find any colored text. I can use both SelectionColor.Name or SelectionBackColor.Name ...

Comment: You need to use the string version of a color name, such as "Red" or "Blue". Which color are you using for the search, I can see if I can reproduce it here.